# android "export android package" overlays gone from mapview signing

Tags: android, export, package, android-mapview

For Now, I'm finished with my application, and I want to put it on the market. (at least, promised myself to have a feature stop till a release... ;)

In debug mode the app words like a charm, it has a mapview on it, with a big overlay (400 items).

When I "export android package", and try the app on my phone, the map works, but the overlays are not displaying.

Things I've allready did/tried;

-got a non-debugger API key for google maps, the map displays, only the overlay's won't...

-Turned off proguard completely; remove the proguard line from 'default.properties'

-I got no errors, the app doesn't crash

Two questions;

1 - Anyone else ever noticed other behavure when 'export android package', if so, what was it? (non-proguard)

2 - Did I turn off proguard the right way?, because I did notice the 'classes.dex' file was quite a bit smaller.

Please try to answer questions 1 and 2 before giving me general hints!

Thanks!

Comment: I've found out that only removing the proguard line from default.properties is not enough, I also have to restart eclipse.

Comment: And indeed, without proguard the program runs fine...

Comment: I'm starting this trouble shooting path;
-first, exclude your main namespace from proguard (proguard.cfg); keep class com.android.helloword** { *; }
-see if the program runs, if so;
-exclude every sub activity/class seperatly and start eliminatin;
keep class com.android.helloword.MainActivity** { *; }

Comment: I'm starting this trouble shooting path;

-first, exclude your main namespace from proguard (proguard.cfg); keep class com.android.helloword** { *; }

-see if the program runs, if so;

-remove this entry; keep class com.android.helloword** { *; }

-exclude every sub activity

keep class com.android.helloword.MainActivity** { *; }

keep class com.android.helloword.OwnClass** { *; }

keep class com.android.helloword.AboutScreen** { *; }


-Start eliminatin;

Comment: This has to do with it; http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/72e5a08da265722c?pli=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson and Proguard were causing it;

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3375947&group_id=54750&atid=474704

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg?r=878

(bottom)

Come to think of it, it all falls into place...